# how to do sorting in moment.js by newest and oldest?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

my array is like this:

```
const myArr = [{text: 'Hello', created: '2018-05-22T08:56:42.491Z'}, {text: 'Hello', created: '2018-05-24T05:56:42.491Z'},]
```

with this kind of array, I want to sort them by newest and oldest, this is my current implementation which does not work:

```
if (sortFilter === 'oldest') {
      contactData = contactData.sort(({ created: prev }, { created: next }) => moment(prev).format('L') - moment(next).format('L'));
    } else if (sortFilter === 'newest') {
      contactData = contactData.sort(({ created: prev }, { created: next }) => moment(next).format('L') - moment(prev).format('L'));
    }
```

what's wrong with my code?

Comment: using `format('L')` the dates are strings ... '5/22/18' and '5/24/18' ... and a "string" - "string" results in `NaN` ... you'll just want `moment(prev) - moment(next)` and `moment(next) - moment(prev)`

Comment: @JaromandaX thanks, removing format('L') worked for me

Answer (score 6):

Without using momentjs, you can use `sort()` and use `new Date()` and convert string to date object.

Newest first.

```js
const myArr = [{
  text: 'Hello',
  created: '2018-05-22T08:56:42.491Z'
}, {
  text: 'Hello',
  created: '2018-05-24T05:56:42.491Z'
}, ];

myArr.sort((a,b)=> new Date(b.created).getTime() - new Date(a.created).getTime());

console.log(myArr);
```

Oldest First:

```js
const myArr = [{
  text: 'Hello',
  created: '2018-05-22T08:56:42.491Z'
}, {
  text: 'Hello',
  created: '2018-05-24T05:56:42.491Z'
}, ];

myArr.sort((a, b) => new Date(a.created).getTime() - new Date(b.created).getTime());

console.log(myArr);
```

Answer (score 4):

You have [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date string which is built to sort lexicographically.

```js
let myArr = [{text: 'Hello', created: '2018-05-22T08:56:42.491Z'}, {text: 'Hello', created: '2018-05-24T05:56:42.491Z'}];
myArr.sort((a,b) => a.created.localeCompare(b.created));
console.log(myArr);
```

Comment: Eventhough its ISO8601, I would still be careful in cases with specific timezones (`"2018-05-24T05:00:00.000Z".localeCompare("2018-05-24T06:00:00.000-08:00") === -1`). It depends on the requirements.

Comment: nice pickup, as long as all date strings are `ZULU` time zone, that's a nice solution!!